# linear-gradient animation based on actual time

Tags: javascript, html, animation, time, background-color

I have a fully working linear-gradient animation based on actual time, BUT the animation is not smooth - it changes every one second because hex changes every second too (let's say it's 15:20:35 so values are: #152035 and #352015).

This is my script -->

```
function background() {
        setInterval(function(){
        var time = new Date();
        var hours = time.getHours();
        var minutes = time.getMinutes();
        var seconds = time.getSeconds();
        if(hours<10){hours = "0" + String(hours);}
        if(minutes<10){minutes = "0" + String(minutes);}
        if(seconds<10){seconds = "0" + String(seconds);} 
        document.getElementById("background").style.background="linear-gradient(#" + hours + minutes + seconds + ", #" + seconds + minutes + hours + ")";
        }, 1000);
    }

    setInterval(function(){
        var time = new Date();
        var hours = time.getHours();
        var minutes = time.getMinutes();
        var seconds = time.getSeconds();
        if(hours<10){hours = "0" + String(hours);}
        if(minutes<10){minutes = "0" + String(minutes);}
        if(seconds<10){seconds = "0" + String(seconds);}
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = (hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
    }, 1000);
```

And this is my Html -->

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="time"></div>
</div>
```

You can check the result [here](http://yamiteru.com/projects/clock/index.html)

My idea is to set the values of linear-gradient equal to a transition between two values (1st = actual time, 2nd = actual time + 1 second).

like this -->

```
//        time 15:20:35
          linear-transition = (function1() {
            animation("#152035", "#152036");
          }, function2() {
              animation("#352015", "#362015");
           };
```

*+Would it be possible to achieve it with a sweep.js?*

Comment: seems smooth enough most of the time - is your issue with e.g. when the seconds roll from :59 to :00 ?   Whatever happens you won't be able to smooth out the usual single increment from one hex value to another - that's a hardware limitation.

Comment: You would do much better if you first converted the time into one value representing number of seconds past in one day. One day has 86400 seconds, you can work pretty conveniently with that. You can then convert the seconds past in a day to percents if you wish. Once you are happy with the convenient values to work with, you can set up some interpolation using getMilliseconds method in Date class. That would make the transition much smoother.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to work with seconds and milliseconds.